# What is the relative running time of this bubble sort derivative?

Tags: sorting, bubble-sort

```
public class Sort {
    public static void sort(int[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                /* swap */
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
                /* make i == -1 because at the end of the loop, it increments to go to 0 */
                i = -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is different from a traditional bubble sort. But does it have a worse running time?

I believe this is still O(N^2), so I do not see how it is any worse...

Comment: @Jens There's nothing language-specific about the algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Funny beast.

Lets take the worst case, an anti-sorted input:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

How many comparisons are needed to move the 9 from the first to the last position?
1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8 = (n-1)*(n-2)/2

What about sending the 8 to the second to last position?
1+2+3+4+5+6+7 = (n-2)*(n-3)/2

So, your algorithm is actually **cubic** in comparisons performed!

Still, there's a light at the end of the tunnel:
It is still only quadratic in the number of swaps performed, like the standard bubble-sort.

Comment: this is the right answer, and please forgive me for my arrogance of forgetting to multiply the array size with the complexity of comparisons for each element. a bad habit that started at college days.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an implementation of bubblesort, although it is not the traditional algorithm. You're right, the algorithm is in O(n^2).

Although this algorithm and the traditional algorithm are the same in terms of asymptotic complexity, the running time on a real machine may differ. Remember that constant factors are omitted when we are looking at O(whatever) complexity. So

```
O(3 n^2) = O(n^2)
```

Keep in mind that O(whatever) are **sets of functions**

Consider traditional bubblesort: Here you go through the entire array by constantly increasing the array index. In this algorithm you make some comparisions that are in fact not needed (because you know when you increment the loop variable of the outer for loop (in traditional bubblesort you have 2 for loops), you know that everything on the left is already sorted. So you don't have to loop over it again.

In practice this will probably not make a difference because the algorithm will need so much time that you will be fed up with it before that effect occurs.